# strings concatenation on variable

Tags: awk, gawk

how to collect add do existing "b" values next matching?

input:

```
1:2:3:4:5
6:7:8:9:0
1:3:2:4:5


$ echo -e "1:2:3:4:5\n6:7:8:9:0\n1:3:2:4:5"|awk -F: '$1=="1"{b="line "NR" "$2;print b}'
line 1 2
line 3 3
```

so finally "b" is set to "line 1 2 line 3 3"

is the something like b=+ in awk?

Comment: `b = b "some string"` ?

Comment: you are right, ...|awk -F: '$1=="1"{b=b"line "NR" "$2" "}END{print b}'